# Difference between sending a transaction with no to field and create() opcode?

Tags: solidity, assembly

What is the difference between sending a transaction with no to field and create() opcode ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both create a contract.

An externally owned account (EOA) creates a contract by sending a transaction with no to field.

A contract (account) creates another contract by using the CREATE opcode.

It's cheaper gas-wise for a contract to create another contract, than an EOA to create a contract (TODO fill in gas costs).  This question inspires [Can the CALL opcode be used to create a contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12210/can-the-call-opcode-be-used-to-create-a-contract)